# django not found Infinite loop

Tags: django

If there is no image, I feel like I'm caught in an infinite loop.

```
{% for test in test_profile %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {%  if  test.path != '' %}
                            <img style=' width:70px;'  src="{% static '/uploads' %}{{ test.path }}/pic_{{ test.name }}" onerror="this.src='/images/template/test_{{ test.gender }}.png';">
                            {%  endif %}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ test.l_idx }}</td>
                        <td>{{ test.l_name }}</td>
                        <td style="padding-left:10px;">{{ test.sub_name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

error message
Infinite loop.....

```
[30/Mar/2019 11:08:11] "GET /images/template/lawyer_0.png HTTP/1.1" 404 37457
Not Found: /images/template/lawyer_1.png
[30/Mar/2019 11:08:11] "GET /images/template/lawyer_1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 37457
Not Found: /images/template/lawyer_0.png
[30/Mar/2019 11:08:11] "GET /images/template/lawyer_0.png HTTP/1.1" 404 37457
Not Found: /images/template/lawyer_1.png
.........................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For template, you can use:

```
 <div class="item-img">
    {% if item.image %}
        <img src="{{ item.image.url }}">
    {% else %}
        <img src="{% static 'assets/static/images/icon.png' %}">
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

For the model, you can use the *get_absolute_url()*:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('list', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
os.path.exists(test.path)
```

instead of

```
*test.path != ''*
```

in your if condition.